# how to get 3rd largest city from each state in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to mongodb and jsp and trying to find out 3rd largest city from each state. I tried it by using $last , $sort and $max functions but not able to solve it.
 I wrote a query to display biggest city in each state:

db.citycollect.aggregate( [ { $group:{_id: { state: "$state", city: "$city" },pop: { $sum: "$pop" }}},{ $sort: { pop: 1 } },{ $group:{_id : "$_id.state",biggestCity: { $last: "$_id.city" },biggestPop: { $last: "$pop" }, smallestCity: { $first: "$_id.city" },smallestPop: { $first: "$pop" }}},{ $project:{ _id: 0, state: "$_id",biggestCity: "$biggestCity"}}] )

Now, I am interested to find out 3rd biggest city in each state. I tried using $skip and $limit but did not get correct output.

Comment: Can you share exactly what you tried, the result you received, and the result you expected?

Comment: Reminds me of an assignment in... M102?

Comment: @JerodJohnson:  wrote a query to display biggest city in each state:

db.citycollect.aggregate( [ { $group:{_id: { state: "$state", city: "$city" },pop: { $sum: "$pop" }}},{ $sort: { pop: 1 } },{ $group:{_id : "$_id.state",biggestCity: { $last: "$_id.city" },biggestPop: { $last: "$pop" }, smallestCity: { $first: "$_id.city" },smallestPop: { $first: "$pop" }}},{ $project:{ _id: 0, state: "$_id",biggestCity: "$biggestCity"}}] )

Now, I am interested to find out 3rd biggest city in each state. I tried using $skip and $limit but did not get correct output.

Comment: @PrajaktaKulkarni Thanks, that gives us an idea of how you're finding the largest city. Can you also share the code you tried when using `$skip` and `$limit`?